# display in AMPL

Tags: display, ampl

when I use :

```
display {(k,m) in YBUS : k==1 }
set {(k,m) in YBUS: k == 1}  := (1,1) (1,2) (1,5);
```

I have variable G for each YBUS elements so I want to display the value of G(1,1) , G(1,2) and G(1,5) so I write :

```
display {(k,m) in YBUS : k==1 }  G(k,m)  ;
```

and it does not work. can anyone help me with the correct format that I should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use square brackets instead of parentheses in subscript:

```
display {(k, m) in YBUS: k == 1} G[k, m];
```